# Why function is undefined in ajax file - does function order matter in AJAX file?

Tags: php, ajax

I am really very surprised to see my function comes out to be undefined on AJAX request. I am wondering does function order matters in AJAX file? Following code will show you my problem -

This is the ajax.php file which is called by jquery/ajax request from index.php. It is supposed to simply print the name -

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
    {
        $name = 'admin';
        echo display_name($name);
        function display_name($name)
        {
            return $name;
        }
    }
?>
```

But when this file is called, i get -

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function display_name()
```

But when i change the order of code i.e. function like this -

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
    {
        $name = 'admin';
        function display_name($name)
        {
            return $name;
        }
        echo display_name($name);
    }
?>
```

then it displays -

```
admin
```

How strange it is!

Thus if really function availability order matters then how the following code works -

It is simple file and it is NOT called by AJAX request. I am simply loading the file and doesn't matter where the function is written. It is working by all using any order of line code -

```
<?php
$name = 'admin';
echo display_name($name);
function display_name($name)
{
    return $name;
}
?>
```

The following snippet is also working -

```
<?php
$name = 'admin';
function display_name($name)
{
    return $name;
}
echo display_name($name);
?>
```

So please tell my the reason behind this difference. In page loading code works and on ajax request it doesn't. Why the function display_name() is undefined if it exists?

Comment: _How strange it is!_???  If you fall from a skyscraper, you do not fall from bottom to top... or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ajax.

From [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, *except* when a function is conditionally defined

The order matters in your first example because the function is *inside an if statement*.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is not related to calling file as Ajax request. This is more related to PHP's function declaration scope.

Consider the following situation:

```
if(true)
{
    function bar()
    {

    }

    $functions = get_defined_functions();
    print_r($functions["user"]);
}

function foo()
{

}
```

this code will give **bar** and **foo** as defined functions.

But the following situation produces just **foo** function:

```
if(true)
{
    $functions = get_defined_functions();
    print_r($functions["user"]);

    function bar()
    {

    }
}

function foo()
{

}
```

From this we see that all the function in a file are defined and available imediately when the file is loaded, but if blocks are interpreted as the execution passes step by step.

Hope this helps.